# How to use ListSerializer with a ModelSerializer?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

I am attempting to create a POST endpoint using DRF ListSerializer to create a list of LogLevel objects.

I have tried to serialize the foreign key using PrimaryKeyRelatedField without success.

```py
models.py
relevant fields for LogLevel model. note foreign key to node model
    #associated node
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                             related_name="log_levels")
    #logger name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=LOGGERS)
    # Current log level
    level = models.IntegerField(default=INFO,
                                choices=LOG_LEVELS)
    # Timestamps
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,
                                            blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
serializers.py
class LogLevelListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        log_levels = [LogLevel(**item) for item in validated_data]
        levels = LogLevel.objects.bulk_create(log_levels)
        return levels


class LogLevelCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LogLevel
        fields = "__all__"
        list_serializer_class = LogLevelListSerializer
```

```py
LogLevel view
class LogLevelList(MethodSerializerMixin,
                   generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Log Level list API Endpoint.
    """
    method_serializer_classes = {
        ("POST",): LogLevelCreateUpdateSerializer
    }

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Queryset to use for endpoint.
        """
        return LogLevel.objects.all()

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
        deserializing input, and for serializing output.
        """
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        # check if many is required
        if "data" in kwargs:
            data = kwargs["data"]

            # check if many is required
            if isinstance(data, list):
                kwargs["many"] = True

        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

MethodSerializerMixin

```py
from rest_framework import exceptions


class MethodSerializerMixin(object):
    """
    Utility class to apply a different serializer class depending
    on the request method.

    For example:

    method_serializer_classes = {
        ("GET", ): MyModelListViewSerializer,
        ("PUT", "PATCH"): MyModelCreateUpdateSerializer
    }
    """
    method_serializer_classes = None

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        assert self.method_serializer_classes is not None, (
            f"Expected view {self.__class__.__name__} should contain "
            f"method_serializer_classes to get right serializer class."
        )
        for methods, serializer_cls in self.method_serializer_classes.items():
            if self.request.method in methods:
                return serializer_cls

        raise exceptions.MethodNotAllowed(self.request.method)
```

Im passing in a json list of simple objects in the request. node is the foreign key id:

```
[{
    "name": "logger1",
    "level": 2,
    "node": 1
},
{
    "name": "logger2",
    "level": 3,
    "node": 1
}]
```

I expect the objects to be created and displayed to the client with success status. Currently, the objects are created in the db successfully but a `500: Server Error` is returned and this is the stacktrace I see on Django server:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/clustering/loglevel/set/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 724, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 697, in get_context
    'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 520, in get_rendered_html_form
    return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 528, in render_form_for_serializer
    serializer.data,
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 765, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 266, in data
    self._data = self.get_initial()
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 600, in get_initial
    return self.to_representation(self.initial_data)
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 527, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/opt/cisco/env/iris/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 257, in to_representation
    return value.pk
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

```
python==3.6
django==2.2.2
drf==3.8.2
```

Comment: I've recreated your code locally, things seems to work without problem, could you share your entire model? both node and loglevel

Comment: also please share your python version, django version and drf version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to handle this error by updating to_representation method on the PrimaryKeyRelatedField class

```py
class NodePrimaryKeyField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    """
    Custom DRF serializer field for proper handling of
    Node Foreign Key by ListSerializer on validation error
    """
    def to_representation(self, value):
        """
        Return pk value of serialized Node object
        if available else return given ID value
        """
        if self.pk_field is not None:
            return self.pk_field.to_representation(value.pk)
        return getattr(value, 'pk', value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `serializer.data` property is only valid if you have a saved an instance to the serializer.
Either call `serializer.save()` or use `serializer.validated_data` to access data prior to saving.

Checkout this [link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2964) for further information.

Comment: just try it for 'self.method_serializer_classes' and if its not suffidient also for 'list_serializer_class'

Comment: my drf knowledge is admittedly weak, still not getting it. youll have to be more specific. so something like LogLevelCreateUpdateSerializer.save() for the serializer_class?

Comment: You could try to add `serializer_cls.save()` bfore the  `return serializer_cls statement`